# ETL with Talend Open Studio

Tags: etl, talend, scd2

SCD
Please someone telling me what the difference between SCD type 2 component and SCD classic with Tmap without component

thanks

[image]

i use SCD type 2 with tmpa but i have problem NullpointerException

Comment: Find the row of code where the tMap goes wrong. It’s usually pretty easy to do so.